# RewriteRule not working, mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: mod-rewrite

I simply want feature.php?id=1 to change to feature/1

mod_rewrite is enable according to php. I tried putting garbage into .htaccess file and that gave me a 500 error, so I'm guessing thats working too.

My **vhosts file**:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/htdocs"
  ServerName test2
  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <Directory "C:/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
  RewriteLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
  RewriteLogLevel 9
</VirtualHost>
```

Contents of my **.htaccess** file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/?feature/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /feature.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And contents of **rewrite.log**

> 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2012:12:23:17 +0100] [test2/sid#2006540][rid#66156b0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/htdocs/feature.php -> feature.php
>   127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2012:12:23:17 +0100] [test2/sid#2006540][rid#66156b0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/htdocs/] applying pattern '^/?feature/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$' to uri 'feature.php'
>   127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2012:12:23:17 +0100] [test2/sid#2006540][rid#66156b0/initial] (1) [perdir C:/htdocs/] pass through C:/htdocs/feature.php

Comment: Please note that stuff has been stripped from my vhosts file by stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Riiiiiight.

I expected the links to re-write themselves. so basically, if I wanted the link to go to  feature/1 I should have made it that. feature.php?id=1 link would not magically change to feature/1 and link to feature/1.

Well, you learn something every day.